# De-Serialize multi line JSON to C# object

Tags: c#, .net, json, .net-core, azure-data-factory

```
 {"ItemName":"8","Id":1}
 {"ItemName":"9","Id":2}
```

I am reading json file from blob, each line has above format and row is not even split by comma and also there is no square brackets in a file.

When i try setting SupportMultipleContent true in jsontextreader i get following exception:

```
 Cannot deserialize the current JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) into type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[ValueDTO]' because the type requires a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) to deserialize correctly.
To fix this error either change the JSON to a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) or change the deserialized type so that it is a normal .NET type (e.g. not a primitive type like integer, not a collection type like an array or List<T>) that can be deserialized from a JSON object. JsonObjectAttribute can also be added to the type to force it to deserialize from a JSON object.
Path 'ItemName', line 1, position 12.
```

Alternatively if parsing of such json is not possible then how would I configure a datafactory in azure to have the file in correct json format.

Code:

```
using (var sr = new StreamReader(stream))
{
    using (var jsonTextReader = new JsonTextReader(sr))
    {
        jsonTextReader.SupportMultipleContent = true;
        while (jsonTextReader.Read())
        {
            var data = serializer.Deserialize<T>(jsonTextReader);
            result.Add(data);
        }

    }
}
```

> Json has no explicit \n character

Comment: In that format it's not one object; you need to parse each line separately and add them to a List.

Comment: How to do that?

Comment: I've tried to [google your error message](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22Json+has+no+explicit+\n+character%22) and only hit is this SO question. Are you sure it's correct?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Each line of your JSON is, by itself, a JSON object. You do not have a JSON array containing all of the objects.

To read it, you just need to rewrite your method to deserialize each line individually:

```
private static List<ValueDTO> LoadItems(Stream stream)
{
    var result = new List<ValueDTO>();
    using (var reader = new StreamReader(stream))
    {
        string line = null;
        while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(line))
            {
                result.Add(JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ValueDTO>(line));
            }
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

[Try it online](https://rextester.com/JUM78348)

Comment: @Sagar compared to what? What are your other options?

Comment: other option is, try to create valid json format in azure databricks

Comment: @Sagar What is the benefit? Doing it that way might actually be less efficient because it forces you to load everything at once. You could modify the above method to use [yield return](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/yield), and then only return rows as you process them, rather than loading them all into memory at once.

Comment: sure i am implementing what you suggested. I will keep you posted. Hope you are around

Comment: i am getting error mentioned in question :Cannot deserialize the current JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) into type System.Collections.Generic.List ValueDTO' because the type requires a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) to deserialize. To fix this error either change the JSON to a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) or change the deserialized type so that it is a normal .NET type (e.g. not a primitive type like integer, not a collection type like an array or List<T>) that can be deserialized from a JSON object. JsonObjectAttribute can also be added to the type to force it to deserialize from a JSON object.

Answer (score 4):

Following code works on my machine. I am using `Newtonsoft.Json` version `12.0.3` targeting `netcoreapp3.0`.

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string json = @"
{'ItemName':'8','Id':1}
{'ItemName':'9','Id':2}
";

            var items = new List<Item>();

            var serializer = new JsonSerializer();

            using (var sr = new StringReader(json))
            {
                using (var jsonTextReader = new JsonTextReader(sr))
                {
                    jsonTextReader.SupportMultipleContent = true;
                    while (jsonTextReader.Read())
                    {
                        var data = serializer.Deserialize<Item>(jsonTextReader);
                        items.Add(data);
                    }

                }
            }

            foreach (Item item in items)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"{item.Id}: {item.ItemName}");
            }
        }
    }

    public class Item
    {
        public string ItemName { get; set; }
        public int Id { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Please use Jsonconvert deserialization method.

```
 List<object> myDeserializedObjList = (List<object>)Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(responseContent, typeof(List<object>));
```