# How to update/modify values in Json File

Tags: c#, arrays, json, streamwriter

I want to update values in the following type of json file in c#

```
{"ItemName":"ABC","Id":1}
{"ItemName":"DEF","Id":2}
{"ItemName":"GHI","Id":3}
{"ItemName":"ABC","Id":1}
{"ItemName":"JKL","Id":2}
{"ItemName":"MNO","Id":3}
```

How can i remove duplicate values based on 'ItemName' and than update Id. Like expected output will be:

```
{"ItemName":"ABC","Id":1}
{"ItemName":"DEF","Id":2}
{"ItemName":"GHI","Id":3}

{"ItemName":"JKL","Id":4}
{"ItemName":"MNO","Id":5}
```

I searched alot about json.writer function but couldn't found a solution for a file without using [] and , seperation.

However i can read the file by using below code

```
var jsonReader = new JsonTextReader(new StringReader(File.ReadAllText("path")))
    {
        SupportMultipleContent = true
    };
var jsonSerializer = new JsonSerializer();

dynamic data = jsonSerializer.Deserialize(jsonReader);

while (jsonReader.Read())
        {                       
            String Items_name = data.ItemName;
        }
```

Comment: the string you posted is not valid json(array).

Comment: Each line of your file is a self-contained JSON object. The file as a whole is _not_ a JSON object. You will have to treat each line separately.

Comment: @DiplomacyNotWar Yes, I am reading the file line by line as shown in above code, so i want to know how can i modify each line by using jsonwriter.

Comment: @LeiYang I am reading this json content from file, and having same type of content in that json file, and its working fine for reading purposes, but i want to write

Comment: You may refer to this one for more clarity of my question.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59043359/de-serialize-multi-line-json-to-c-sharp-object

Comment: `jsonReader.Read()` will read token-by-token for the first entry in the file. Please see [this example](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/ReadMultipleContentWithJsonReader.htm) in the documentation for the correct way to do it.

Comment: Deser each line of the file, dedupe, reser..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a class to deser to:

```
public record X(string ItemName, int Id);
```

You read your file deser'ing each line:

```
var xs = File.ReadAllLines("path").Select(l => JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<X>(l)).ToList();
```

You remove your duplicates:

```
var deduped = xs.DistinctBy(x => x.ItemName);
```

and perform your other manipulations etc (maybe you will want to call ToList on the above). Then you reserialize:

```
File.WriteAllLines("path", deduped.Select(x => JsonConvert.SerializeObject(x)).ToArray());
```

Comment: can you please tell me a bit more about 'public record X(string ItemName, int Id); '  . why we are using this? and how to use it. I am sorry i am begginer to both json C# and json formats.

Comment: It's a class representing the json objects in the file

Comment: ' public class X
        {
            [JsonProperty("Id")]
            public int Id{ get; set; }

            [JsonProperty("item")]
            public string item { get; set; }
        } '     like this?

Comment: Like that, though those JsonProperty are redundant because they merely repeat the exact spelling and capilatization of the properties. Also, "item" doesn't actually match the property in your json. If you want to pt code in comments, surround it in a backtick ` at either end, not an apostrophe. There should be no space between the backtick and the code

Comment: You can read about records here:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/csharp-9#record-types

Comment: I am using the below code `public class get_data
{
     public string ItemName;
     public int Id;
}
private void Form_1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{    
      var deserial_list = File.ReadAllLines(@"./sample.json").Select(l => JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<get_data>(l)).ToList();
      var deduped = deserial_list.Select(get_data => get_data.ItemName).Distinct();
      File.WriteAllLines(@"./sample_updated.json", deduped.Select(get_data => JsonConvert.SerializeObject(get_data)).ToArray());
}` but not getting the required output as in next comment.

Comment: but getting results as `"ABC"
"DEF"
"GHI"
"JKL"
"MNO"
` not the complete json file. I am not getting my mistake, where i am doing something wrong?

Comment: I used DistinctBy deliberately; a Select.Distinct is not the same. Select extracts just the ItemName and throws the rest away, so you lose the ID. If you're on a version of .net that doesn't have DistinctBy, you can do the same with `.GroupBy(x => x.ItemName, (k,g) => g.First())`

Comment: It worked. learned a lot. Thank you very much for your too much support.

Comment: You're most welcome