# c# reading json file, 'Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: s. Path '', line 0, position 0.'

Tags: c#, json, json.net, blazor, deserialization

I'm currently using **Blazor WebAssembly**.
This is the error i'm getting when I try to Deserialize with the nuGet Newtonsoft.Json.
*'Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: s. Path '', line 0, position 0.'*

This is my **JSON file** :

```
[{
    "Id": 1,
    "Brand": "Aprilia",
    "Modele": "RS 660",
    "CC": 660,
    "Nb Cylindre": 2,
    "Config cylindre": "ligne",
    "Couple": "66 Nm 8500",
    "Puissance (kW)": "XXX",
    "Puissance (cv)": "100 cv 10500",
    "Poids sec (kg)": 169,
    "Date sortie": 2023
}, {
    "Id": 2,
    "Brand": "Aprilia",
    "Modele": "Tuono 660",
    "CC": 660,
    "Nb Cylindre": 2,
    "Config cylindre": "ligne",
    "Couple": "66 Nm 8500",
    "Puissance (kW)": "XXX",
    "Puissance (cv)": "95 cv 10500",
    "Poids sec (kg)": 183,
    "Date sortie": 2023
}]
```

And my **object **:

```
public class MotoDTO
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Brand { get; set; }
        public string Modele { get; set; }
        public int CC { get; set; }
        public int NbCylindre { get; set; }
        public string ConfigCylindre { get; set; }
        public string Couple { get; set; }
        public string PuissanceKW { get; set; }
        public string PuissanceCv { get; set; }
        public int PoidsSecKg { get; set; }
        public int DateSortie { get; set; }
    }
```

And finaly, this is where the **error **occurs :

```
            try
            {
                var serializer = new JsonSerializer();

                using (var sr = new StringReader(jsonFile))
                {
                    using (var jsonTextReader = new JsonTextReader(sr))
                    {
                        jsonTextReader.SupportMultipleContent = true;
            here -->    while (jsonTextReader.Read())
                        {
                            var moto = serializer.Deserialize<MotoDTO>(jsonTextReader);
                            _motos.Add(moto);
                        }

                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                string msg = ex.Message;
            }
```

Could somebody help me ?
Thanks

I got the code here [https://stackoverflow.com](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59043359/de-serialize-multi-line-json-to-c-sharp-object)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string json = @"
{'ItemName':'8','Id':1}
{'ItemName':'9','Id':2}
";

            var items = new List<Item>();

            var serializer = new JsonSerializer();

            using (var sr = new StringReader(json))
            {
                using (var jsonTextReader = new JsonTextReader(sr))
                {
                    jsonTextReader.SupportMultipleContent = true;
                    while (jsonTextReader.Read())
                    {
                        var data = serializer.Deserialize<Item>(jsonTextReader);
                        items.Add(data);
                    }

                }
            }

            foreach (Item item in items)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"{item.Id}: {item.ItemName}");
            }
        }
    }

    public class Item
    {
        public string ItemName { get; set; }
        public int Id { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Does your file begin and end with `[]` or does it not? You seem to have two versions? If yes why bother with `SupportMultipleContent` just deserialize straight into a `List<Item>`

Comment: That code along with that JSON does not throw that exception. Provide a proper [mre]. How do you initialize the `jsonFile`? According to the exception message, its contents start with an "s".

Comment: @Charlieface, yes it ends and starts with `[]`. Should I juste delete the `SupportMultipleContent` line ?

Comment: @CodeCaster, this is the var where is ma json file : `private readonly string jsonFile = "sample-data/DB_Moto.json";`.

Comment: Yeah so you need a StreamReader (which reads the file at the path you pass it), not a StringReader (which turns a string, in this case the path string, into a stream).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You Dto's property names do not match the json data.
And you want to deserialize to a single Dto but your json data is an array.
Here's who you can deszerialize it:

```
 public void Deserialize()
    {
        string jsonData = @"[
    {
        ""Id"": 1,
        ""Brand"": ""Aprilia"",
        ""Modele"": ""RS 660"",
        ""CC"": 660,
        ""Nb Cylindre"": 2,
        ""Config cylindre"": ""ligne"",
        ""Couple"": ""66 Nm 8500"",
        ""Puissance (kW)"": ""XXX"",
        ""Puissance (cv)"": ""100 cv 10500"",
        ""Poids sec (kg)"": 169,
        ""Date sortie"": 2023
    },
    {
        ""Id"": 2,
        ""Brand"": ""Aprilia"",
        ""Modele"": ""Tuono 660"",
        ""CC"": 660,
        ""Nb Cylindre"": 2,
        ""Config cylindre"": ""ligne"",
        ""Couple"": ""66 Nm 8500"",
        ""Puissance (kW)"": ""XXX"",
        ""Puissance (cv)"": ""95 cv 10500"",
        ""Poids sec (kg)"": 183,
        ""Date sortie"": 2023
    }
    ]";

        var obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<MotoDTO>>(jsonData);

    }
```

The adjusted DTO

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;

  public class MotoDTO
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Brand { get; set; }
        public string Modele { get; set; }
        public int CC { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("Nb Cylindre")]
        public int NbCylindre { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("Config cylindre")]
        public string ConfigCylindre { get; set; }
        public string Couple { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("Puissance (kW)")]
        public string PuissanceKW { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("Puissance (cv)")]
        public string PuissanceCv { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("Poids sec (kg)")]
        public int PoidsSecKg { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("Date sortie")]
        public int DateSortie { get; set; }
    }
```

Now in order to fetch the file from the wwwroot folder you have to use the httpClient

```
@inject HttpClient Client

@code
{

    private List<MotoDTO> motos;

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        motos = await LoadMotosFromJsonAsync();
    }

    private async Task<List<MotoDTO>> LoadMotosFromJsonAsync()
    {
        var response = await Client.GetAsync("sample-data/DB_Moto.json");

        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            var content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<MotoDTO>>(content);
        }
        else
        {
            return new List<MotoDTO>();
        }
    }
}
```

please make sure the HttpClient is registerd in the app

```
public static async Task Main(string[] args)
        {
            var builder = WebAssemblyHostBuilder.CreateDefault(args);
            builder.RootComponents.Add<App>("#app");
            builder.RootComponents.Add<HeadOutlet>("head::after");
            builder.Services.AddScoped(sp => new HttpClient { BaseAddress = new Uri(builder.HostEnvironment.BaseAddress) });

            await builder.Build().RunAsync();
        }
```

Comment: when i add `JsonProperty()` i get this error : `The type or namespace name 'JsonPropertyAttribute' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)`

Comment: using Newtonsoft.Json;

Comment: now i get this error : `'Could not find a part of the path '/sample-data/DB_Moto.json'.'`, I'm using Blazor WebAssembly.

Comment: Is the file local on the client or on the server? If it is local try the wwwroot folder to store it. If it is on the server you have to make an httprequest to get it.

Comment: it's in the wwwroot. Here is the complete path : `"C:\tools\_MotoProjectDavid\MotoProjectDavid\MotoProjectDavid\Client\wwwroot\sample-data\DB_Moto.json"`. I already had that error but can't remember how I fixed it.

Comment: Here's how you solve this problem.  Make sample data in C# and serialize it to an object.  This will show you what format the deserializer is expecting.  You can parse your incoming string to comform, or adjust your class to accept the data in its current form.

Comment: Also-- don't use Newtonsoft, Json is now built into .net.

Comment: i have updated the answer based on your szenario

Comment: @Bennyboy1973, so what should I use instead of Newtonsoft.json ???

Comment: @jeb, I now get an error with the code you wrote.
In the `OninitializedAsync` and in this line :
`return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<MotoDTO>>(content);`

Comment: You are a developer. At least tell what error message you are getting. Is it a compilation error or a runtime error ? Did you try to debug the code setting a breakpoint.

Comment: @jeb sorry my fault forgetting, here is the error : `'Error converting value {null} to type 'System.Int32'. Path '[33].CC', line 401, position 9.'`. How can I avoid getting that error just because the field is empty ?

Comment: try making it nullable `public int CC` -> `public int? CC`

Comment: @jeb, I tried it but I got an even bigger error. here's 2 lines of it : 
`at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RenderTree.RenderTreeDiffBuilder.AppendDiffEntriesForRange(DiffContext& diffContext, Int32 oldStartIndex, Int32 oldEndIndexExcl, Int32 newStartIndex, Int32 newEndIndexExcl) at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RenderTree.RenderTreeDiffBuilder.AppendDiffEntriesForFramesWithSameSequence(DiffContext& diffContext, Int32 oldFrameIndex, Int32 newFrameIndex)`

Comment: @David No Idea maybe you use the list before it's initalized, you can try  private List<MotoDTO> motos = new();

Comment: @David You can use System.Text.Json: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json/how-to?pivots=dotnet-7-0  There's nothing WRONG with Newtonsoft, but you can drop that extra dependency.

Comment: @jeb, it worked I just had to make every int nullable. Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

you don't have any multiline , it is just a json array, so since you are using json.net

```
var json = File.ReadAllText(@"C:\... .json");

List<MotoDTO> motoDtos = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<MotoDTO>>(json);

public class MotoDTO
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Brand { get; set; }
    public string Modele { get; set; }
    public int CC { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("Nb Cylindre")]
    public int NbCylindre { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("Config cylindre")]
    public string ConfigCylindre { get; set; }
    public string Couple { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("Puissance (kW)")]
    public string PuissanceKW { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("Puissance (cv)")]
    public string PuissanceCv { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("Poids sec (kg)")]
    public int PoidsSecKg { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("Date sortie")]
    public int DateSortie { get; set; }
}
```

if for some reason you want something async, it is better to use System.Text.Json

Comment: i get an error when I test your way.
I posted it as an answer. Could you check it please ?
Thanks a lot.

Comment: @David I always test my code before posting.  You better recheck a json file, is it the same json inside and check file path as well.

Comment: I get that error :
`'Could not find a part of the path '/sample-data/DB_Moto.json'.'`

My json file is in the 'wwwroot/sample-data/'